# Laravel 7.x Blade {!! !}} escaped question mark symbol (?) though it is not included in php htmlspecialchars

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, html-escape-characters, laravel-7

In blade.php file, i used `{!! $imageLink !!}`

`$imageLink` is "mysite.com/my_image.png?version=1586505972".

But when i inspected elements, it become "mysite.com/my_image.png%3Fversion%3D1586505972"

Although the symbol ? not included in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason
`$imageLink` is actually encoded before passing to blade, it's from `return Storage::url($image);`